# HTML table data into Excel cell usin POI java

Tags: java, html, excel, apache-poi

Can you please let me know how can we render the html table data into Excel cell using Apache POI in java.
I have the below requirement like ..

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:500px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>details</td>
<td>testing</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>1</td>
<td>220</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>10</td>
</tr></tbody>
</table>
```

but its just coming as text string ..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwPjP.png)

Comment: Please share the code what you have tried.

Comment: Parse the HTML, then generate the required rows and cells into the Excel file?

Answer (score 0):

Here basically you need to parse and convert HTML to data rows and then finally write to excel. I will show you how to do it using Gradle, Jsoup and apache poi

You need following dependency in your build.gradle

```
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:5.0.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.0.0'
    implementation group: 'org.jsoup', name: 'jsoup', version: '1.11.3'
```

And here is the code to convert and write to excel

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFont;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //HTML to Data
        String data = "<table border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"1\" cellspacing=\"1\" style=\"width:500px;\">\n" +
            "<tbody>\n" +
            "<tr>\n" +
            "<td>details</td>\n" +
            "<td>testing</td>\n" +
            "</tr>\n" +
            "<tr><td>1</td>\n" +
            "<td>220</td>\n" +
            "</tr>\n" +
            "<tr><td>3</td>\n" +
            "<td>4</td>\n" +
            "<td>10</td>\n" +
            "</tr></tbody>\n" +
            "</table>";
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(data);
        Element table = doc.select("table").get(0); //select the first table.
        Elements rows = table.select("tr");
        Element headerRow = rows.get(0);
        List<String> headers = new ArrayList<>();
        List<List<String>> dataRows = new ArrayList<>();
        Elements headerColumns = headerRow.select("td");
        for (int l = 0; l < headerColumns.size(); l++) {
            headers.add(headerColumns.get(l).text());
        }
        System.out.println(headers);
        for (int i = 1; i < rows.size(); i++) {
            Element row = rows.get(i);
            Elements cols = row.select("td");
            List<String> dataRow = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int j = 0; j < cols.size(); j++) {
                dataRow.add(cols.get(j).text());
            }
            dataRows.add(dataRow);
        }
        //Data to excel
        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("data");
        Row header = sheet.createRow(0);
        for (int k = 0; k < headers.size(); k++) {
            Cell headerCell = header.createCell(k);
            headerCell.setCellValue(headers.get(k));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < dataRows.size(); i++) {
            Row r = sheet.createRow(i + 1);
            List<String> d = dataRows.get(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < d.size(); j++) {
                Cell dataCell = r.createCell(j);
                dataCell.setCellValue(d.get(j));
           }
        }

        File currDir = new File(".");
        String path = currDir.getAbsolutePath();
        String fileLocation = path.substring(0, path.length() - 1) + "Data.xlsx";

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileLocation);
        workbook.write(outputStream);
        workbook.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you suggesting such an old, unsupported version of Apache POI?

Comment: library version updated

Comment: Thanks for your effort and quick response ..but i need to add this entire table data into a one column cell in excel sheet .
this is giving different cells and data.

Comment: There are multiple columns in the excel how are going to fit it in excel? give us an example for your data

Comment: thanks for the update @Mystrery  ..below table need to be render into a cell  as like table (Just example ),it has 5 rows and 2 columns .. it may vary .

<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:500px;"><tbody><tr><td>123</td><td>cards</td></tr><tr><td>1234</td><td>card details</td></tr><tr><td>123456</td><td>card details info</td></tr><tr><td>card details</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>card details</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody></table><p>&nbsp;</p>